# Remove text from string

Tags: r, tidyverse, gsub

I'm trying to remove the text " 12:00:00 AM" from the string e.g: "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" from the column "ActivityDate"

I'm using this pipe:

```
Sleep <- sleepDay_merged %>%
  rename('ActivityDate' = 'SleepDay') %>%
  gsub("12:00:00 AM","",'ActivityDate')
```

And I get this error:

In addition:

```
Warning message:
In sub(., "12:00:00 AM", "", "ActivityDate") :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Could please help me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues. Use `gsub` (or just `sub` if you have only one replacement) in `mutate`. Also, the column `ActivityDate` should not be in quotes (`""`). Try with -

```
library(dplyr)

Sleep <- sleepDay_merged %>%
  rename('ActivityDate' = 'SleepDay') %>%
  mutate(ActivityDate = gsub("12:00:00 AM","",ActivityDate))
```